# difference between extends inner class and extends nested class?

Tags: java, inheritance, nested, inner-classes, extends

```
class OuterClass
{
    static class InnerClassOne
    {
        //Class as a static member
    }

    class InnerClassTwo
    {
        //Class as a non-static member
    }
}


class AnotherClassOne extends OuterClass.InnerClassOne
{

}


class AnotherClassTwo extends OuterClass.InnerClassTwo
{
    public AnotherClassTwo()
    {
        new OuterClass().super();  //accessing super class constructor through OuterClass instance
    }
}
```

i have theses classes, why when extends from nested class we do not call outer class constructor , but when extends from inner class should call outer constructor through outer object, so what is the difference and why??

Comment: in short , one is static like ready to eat or other one is non-static , need some cooking to use it, read about static and then inner-static class , it will be totally clear & read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. To access a `static` property you don't need to create an object i.e. you don't need to instantiate the class.

But if you want to access a **non static** property you will first need to create an object of that class and then use it.

So here in your case when you want to extend `InnerClassTwo`(which is an inner class and non static) you will have to associate it with the constructor of the outer class `AnotherClassTwo`, as it can be thought of as a property of that outer class.